# Image gallery next button update alt from ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, image-gallery, alt

I am trying to make a simple image gallery. This is what I have now:

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/rgvqA/

```javascript
var NumberOfImages = 7;

var img = new Array(NumberOfImages);

img[0] = "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers600/number0.jpg";
img[1] = "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers600/number1.jpg";
img[2] = "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers600/number2.jpg";
img[3] = "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers600/number3.jpg";
img[4] = "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers600/number4.jpg";
img[5] = "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers600/number5.jpg";
img[6] = "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers600/number6.jpg";

var imgNumber = 0

    function NextImage() {
        imgNumber++;
        if (imgNumber == NumberOfImages) {
            imgNumber = 0;
        }    
        document.images["largeImage"].src = img[imgNumber];
    }

    function PreviousImage() {
        imgNumber--;
        if (imgNumber < 0) {
            imgNumber = NumberOfImages - 1;
        }
        document.images["largeImage"].src = img[imgNumber];
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thumbs').delegate('img', 'click', function() {
        imgNumber = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});

$('#thumbs').delegate('img', 'click', function () {
    $('#largeImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
    $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

**The problem**: When I click the `next` and `previous` buttons, the alt text for the description does not change accordingly. It only does when I click the thumbnail.

How do I update the `alt` text to whatever image is currently displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image caption isn't getting set with the arrow button clicks, because the functions they call (`NextImage` and `PreviousImage`) do not have any code which updates it.

You can use `imgNumber` to retrieve the correct thumb image, get it's alt text, and update the description element with it:

```
$('#description').html($('#'+imgNumber).attr('alt'));
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rgvqA/2/
you just forgot to update your `$('#description')` element in next and prev functions

Comment: btw, you have wrong #description value at the moment of page is loaded. it's a zero image)

Answer (score 0):

This causes because of your code ( `$('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));` ) Where `this` refers to the small thumb. So you are getting the alt text from the thumb.

Try to crete the description in an array like above you did for images.

`var desc = new Array(NumberOfImages);`

```
`desc[0] = "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers600/number0.jpg";
desc[1] = "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers600/number1.jpg";
desc[2] = "http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/numbers600/number2.jpg";
desc[3] = "http://www.kidsmath`
```

Call here

```
    function NextImage() {
        imgNumber++;
        if (imgNumber == NumberOfImages) {
        imgNumber = 0;
        }    
        document.images["largeImage"].src = img[imgNumber];
        var desc = desc[imgNumber];
        $('#description').text(desc);
    }

    function PreviousImage() {
        imgNumber--;
        if (imgNumber < 0) {
        imgNumber = NumberOfImages - 1;
        }
        document.images["largeImage"].src = img[imgNumber];
        var desc = desc[imgNumber];
        $('#description').text(desc);
    }
```